# Why do we need a symmetric matrix for the threshold current at a magnetic neutral point?

Tags: linear-algebra, magnetohydrodynamics

1

I'm reviewing a paper for my final year BS project and I seem to be confused on a step that the author takes. The following part is from the paper itself.

"**2.1. The Threshold Current.**
From the square root of the discriminant of the characteristic equation of the symmetric part of M, we define a threshold current:
$$M_{s}=\frac{1}{2}(M+M^{T})$$
$$J_{threshold}=\sqrt{4p2+q2}$$"

I can do the mathematics for how the relation is derived, but I don't get the physical reason for it.

P.S. The matrix M is defined as:

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
p & \frac{1}{2}(q - J_{z})\\
\frac{1}{2}(q + J_{z}) & -p
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where Jz
is the current density in the z
direction and p
& q
are just some parameters that we use.

Comment: Could you please give a link to the original paper?

Comment: "https://www.researchgate.net/publication/363094365_The_Australian_Journal_of_Mathematical_Analysis_and_Applications_AJMAA_KINEMATIC_MODEL_FOR_MAGNETIC_NULL-POINTS_IN_2_DIMENSIONS" Here you go @Luessiaw

Comment: There's no need for $M$ to be symmetric. Sect. 2.3 of the paper sloves the general case. I think in Sect. 2.1 the symmetric part is used to define the threshold current naturally, whose physical meaning is mentioned in following sections.

Comment: Thanks @Luessiaw. But I do have a question, What is the logic for defining the threshold current as the **discriminant** of the characteristic equation? and physically it's still not very clear what this threshold current actually is.